# How to partition users ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identitymanager

I am working through examples of using Thinktecture's IdentityServer v3 along with ASP.NET Identity. I see that ASP.NET Identity is set up to manage users by roles and claims. Is there any feature that allows you to partition users such that the same user name can exist in different partitions.

If so how would one go about modifying the IdentityManager sample project (https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/wiki) to include this parameter on the interface? I am having a very difficult time understanding the IdentityManager project, because there are no views or html files or controllers in the host project to help figure out how the pages are being served.

Comment: Not sure what you mean that "partition users such that the same user name can exist in different partitions". what does "partitions" mean? Are you looking for MultiTenant?

Answer (score 1):

For IdentityServer 3, I am successfully using https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot instead of ASP.net Identity to get multitenancy support(i.e same username can exist in multiple tenants). But be aware that this project is no longer maintained. Also, have a look into https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Quick-and-Easy-ASPNET-Identity-Multitenancy for multitenant example in asp.net identity if it meets your requirement.

For Identity Manager, you can do few modifications to display a drop down list of tenants to select when creating a new user(`\Core\Assets\Templates\users\new.html`) and display additional tenant column in `\Core\Assets\Templates\users\list.html` . You will be required to go through the identity manager code a little to achieve what you want.

Comment: I don't think multi-tenancy is exactly what I need. I've decided to not use ASP.NET identity so I can utilize our existing user tables.